# How do I add DevOps Permissions

Tags: azure-devops

How do I grant permissions in Azure DevOps to create pulls?

See the attached screenshot image file for details. https://github.zendesk.com/attachments/token/3n94qn1KDz53kxCMwGXGBKleV/?name=Screenshot+2020-12-11+034803.png
Hal

Comment: Hello there, is there any updates for this issue? You can check whether Abra's answer can help you can feel free to comment~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things to ask yourself:

#### Does the user have a license?

In Azure DevOps, go to Organization Settings -> Users.
Locate the user and select "Change access level".

Change the access level from Stakeholder to ie. Basic.

#### Does the user have permission to "Contribute to pull request"

This permission is granted by the Contributer group by default.
In Azure DevOps go to your Project -> Project Settings -> Permissions -> Contributers
Add the user to the Contributers group.

Comment: When I made an attempt to add permission to "Contribute to pull request," I received the following error: 

"Invite members to Contributors
Search and add users and/or groups to your group

Add users and/or groups 
Ajay XXX is/are already direct or indirect member(s) of this group."


https://github.com/CforED/datasciencecoursera.git

Comment: That error would indicate the user is already a contributer. Did you try to change the users Access Level as suggested above? You can check if he has the "Contribute to pull request" permission by going to Project Settings -> Repositories -> Permissions. Search for the user, and the "Contribute to pull request" should be set to Allow.

Comment: @Harold H. Agree with Abra's suggestion about user's access level. I have reproduced your error by changing a reviewer's access level from Basic to Stakeholder.